# How to rebuild patched version of a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

just would like to learn how to rebuild ruby's gem without a gemspec:

for example trying to create fixed gem for Gosu library:

1. download the gem with `gem fetch gosu`
2. extract contents of the gem with `gem unpack gosu-0.7.45.gem`
3. apply a patch: `cd gosu-0.7.45 && patch -p1 /path/to/patch/fix_cflags.patch`
4. **??? how to rebuild a gem from modified sources ? I cann't find the
   original gemspec.**

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question:

4a. Extract gemspec file by `gem unpack --spec <gem archive>`

4b. Rebuild updated gem from the top of the source tree with `gem build /path/to/<gemspec>`

Comment: If you are running into `Invalid gemspec [...] syntax error, unexpected tLABEL`, use `gem spec my_gem-1.0.gem --ruby > my_gem-1.0/my_gem-1.0.gemspec` instead of *4a* to extract the gemspec in Ruby format instead of YAML.